# Ubuntu 14.04 update wants to remove ubuntu-mate-desktop?

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, updates, mate

I've seen [Apt wants to remove ubuntu-mate-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628320/apt-wants-to-remove-ubuntu-mate-desktop), but this is different.

I use MATE desktop, and my Ubuntu is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux MYPC 4.2.0-36-generic #42~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 13 17:27:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS \n \l
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Just today, I was thinking of doing an upgrade:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default
  libcompizconfig0 libdecoration0 overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport apport-gtk libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6:i386 libc6-dbg libc6-dev
  libc6-i386 libpam-smbpass libsmbclient libwbclient0 multiarch-support
  python-samba python3-apport python3-problem-report samba samba-common
  samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules smbclient
23 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 33.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] ^C
```

Oh, I thought, some packages are held back, why not update them with `dist-upgrade`?

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  compiz-mate ubuntu-mate-desktop
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport apport-gtk compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins
  compiz-plugins-default libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6:i386 libc6-dbg
  libc6-dev libc6-i386 libcompizconfig0 libdecoration0 libpam-smbpass
  libsmbclient libwbclient0 multiarch-support python-samba python3-apport
  python3-problem-report samba samba-common samba-common-bin
  samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules smbclient
30 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 29.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,128 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] ^C
```

B... but wait, I do **not** want to remove `ubuntu-mate-desktop`, I am using it! So what is going on, why does the update want to remove `ubuntu-mate-desktop`? How should I do the update, so I keep `ubuntu-mate-desktop`?

---

EDIT: I let the `dist-upgrade` go so `ubuntu-mate-desktop` is removed; thankfully it is just a metapackage, so I still have MATE running after reboot, but now I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-mate-desktop : Depends: compiz-mate but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Why, oh why, ... can't `compiz-mate` and `compiz-gnome` just coexist? Why is it necessary to break my system? ...